# How to be aware of the creation of a new event in a google calendar?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I'm looking for a mechanism like [Google calendarList watch API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendarList/watch) to be notified when a new event is created in a specific google calendar instead of polling.

According to the documentation it seems there's no option for watching a calendar by a webhook.
I saw there are `watch` for events and calendarList, but I want to be notified by `watch` mechanism whenever a new event is created in a calendar.

Is there any solution to do that?